# Why is the problem infeasible?

Tags: cvx, cvxpy

Given $\mathbf V_t=\mathbf v_t\mathbf v_t^H$ where $\mathbf v_t=\left(e^{j\theta_{1}},e^{j\theta_{2}}\right)^H$:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{ll}
\underset{\mathbf V}{\operatorname{minimize}} & 1 \\
\text { subject to } & \operatorname{diag}(\mathbf V)=1\\
&\|\mathbf V\|_*-\operatorname{trace}\left[\boldsymbol\lambda\boldsymbol\lambda^H\left(\mathbf V-\mathbf V_t\right)\right]-\|\mathbf V_t\|_2\leq 0
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
where $\|\bullet\|_*$ and $\|\bullet\|_2$ is the nuclear norm and 2-norm. $\boldsymbol\lambda$ is the leading eigenvector of $\mathbf V_t$.

**Since $\mathbf V=\mathbf V_t$ is a feasible solution, the optimization problem is feasible. Why does CVX show the problem is infeasible?**

```matlab
clear;clc;close all;

Vt = rand(2,1);
Vt = (exp(1i*Vt)*exp(1i*Vt)');
[lambda,~] = eigs(Vt,1,'largestabs');
cvx_begin sdp
    variable V(2,2) hermitian semidefinite
    minimize(1)
    subject to
        diag(V) == 1
        norm_nuc(V) - real(trace(lambda*lambda'*(V-Vt))) - norm(Vt,2) <= 0
cvx_end
```

[image]

Comment: it solves for me to optimlaity, i.e., finds a feasible solution, using several different random number draws and all of Mosek, SeDuMi, and SDPT3.  Can you poist reproducible code, copied and pasted, not an image, and show us a complete MATLAB session exhibiting infeasibility? Display the values of Vt and lambda.

Comment: I copied and pasted, and ran it multiple times (with different random mumbers) for all 3 solvers, and it solved every time.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortunately, I could not get the correct result with CVX. Could you show me your results?

Comment: All real and imaginary elements of V-Vt are less than 1r-9, 1e-10, 1e-15 in magnitude respectively for SeDuMi, SDPT3, Mosek. The exact output varies when random numbers are changed. Try running your program starting from a fresh MATLAB session.

Comment: In the problem, we should not constrain the magnitude of $\mathbf V-\mathbf V_t$. $\mathbf V=\mathbf V_t$ only means the problem is feasible.

Comment: I ran the code you provided. I was merely describing the results, i.e., the solvers always returned solution V within solver tolerance of Vt. However, the solver is "allowed" to produce any other feasible solution it "wants to". If I change the objective to `minimize(real(V(1,2)))`, the solution deviates from Vt. Such solution would also be allowed under the original objective, which is really just a feasibility problem, and is the same as providing no objective at all to CVX. V = Vt is indeed feasible, but there are an infinity of other feasible solutions as well.

Comment: Your code and logic are fine. Something is screwed up in your MATLAB, CVX, or solver installation or session.